# Как создать базу данных и добавить в неё список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sqlite3, insert

Нужно создать какую либо базу данных и добавить в неё список. 
Пытался сделать так, но не получается. (базу данных я создал отдельно)

**main.py**:

```
import sqlite3

lst = [5, 5, 5, 4, 5]

con = sqlite3.connect('daatass.db')


def sql_insert(con, lst):

    cursorObj = con.cursor()
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        cursorObj.execute('INSERT INTO employees(maths) Values(?)', lst[i])

    con.commit()


sql_insert(con, lst)
```

Comment: Fahhov, а тег `pyqt5` вы указали для чего?

Comment: Nick, оой, я случайно, просто часто его указываю)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```
import sqlite3

lst = [5, 5, 5, 4, 5]

con = sqlite3.connect('q1514975_daatass.db')

def sql_insert(con, lst):

    cursorObj = con.cursor()
    cursorObj.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees(maths INTEGER);")
#   for i in range(len(lst)):
    for i in lst:
#        cursorObj.execute('INSERT INTO employees(maths) VALUES(?)', i)
        cursorObj.execute('INSERT INTO employees VALUES ({0})'.format(i))
    con.commit()


sql_insert(con, lst)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!)